# Do I size a 24 V transformer based on 120 V load current?

Tags: power-supply

Do I size a 24 V transformer based on 120 V load current?

I have a 120 V feed through a switch. From switch to input of transformer (black). (120 V to 24 V transformer - 40 VA – gives 1.66 A available). The transformer feeds the thermostat ONLY.

The output of the transformer (white) feeds to 120 V load. The load then completes the circuit to neutral. The 120 V load is rated at 93 W (0.78 A).

Have I looked at this application correctly by using (comparing) the amperage of the 120 V load to the amperage available at the 24 V transformer?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Restate: Only 24V component is the thermostat. the load (fan) is back on the 120V side of the transformer.  This is used for an HVAC application, for the thermostat to control the 120v duct fan.

Answer (score 1):

You size a transformer by the VA of the load. The VA input requirement will be the VA output requirement + some losses in the transformer itself.

> 40 VA – gives 1.66 A available.

Your calculation is correct.

The rest of your post is quite garbled.

- Transformers are wired with their primary connected directly between L and N. The primary is NOT connected between L and the load. (The exception to this would be some kind of current transformer but that's not what you are describing.)
- If there is a 24 V transformer it's usually because the LOAD is 24 V and the voltage must be stepped down.

Tip: 'V' or 'volt'. 'A' or 'amp(ere)'. 'W' or 'watt'. (I fixed your question.)